# How can I find all rows with a value in one column which corresponds to more than one value in another column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find out how many values in column A correspond to more than one value in column B.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 2 | dog |
| 3 | rat |
| 1 | horse |
| 1 | cat |
| 2 | bird |
| 3 | rat |

How can I loop through all of the values in A and get an output which tells me:

1 has cat and horse

2 has dog and bird

Comment: `df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(list)`?

Comment: To go off @DaniMesejo answer, maybe shove `unique` in there too: `df.groupby('A')['B'].unique().agg(list)` or make it a set: `df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(set)`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know which values match your condition:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep=False), 'A'].unique()
```

output: `array([2, 1])`

To get the values:

```
out = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(set)
out = out[out.str.len()>1]
```

output:

```
A
1    {cat, horse}
2     {bird, dog}
Name: B, dtype: object
```